# ImageView or VideoView, which should I display my streaming "video" in android?

Tags: android, python, opencv, video, streaming

I have an android App (native) which streaming video from other camera.

I created a simple server with `python`, `flask`, and `opencv` (to process the video)

```
from mockCamera import VideoCamera;

import time
import argparse
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, jsonify, url_for, send_file



# Gallery folder name
STATIC_FOLDER = 'gallery'


# Init Flask app & Camera object
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder=STATIC_FOLDER)

def gen(camera):
    """Video streaming generator function."""
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield(b'--frame\r\n'
          b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    """Video streaming route."""
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()),
                mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-c", "--camera", help="URL of IP Camera")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())

    # If the camera argument is not None,
    # then we set it to CAMERA_URL variable
    # otherwise we use default value
    if args.get('camera', None) is not None:
    CAMERA_URL = args['camera']

# Run the app
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

`camera.get_frame()` will return a frame which processed by opencv

So now, I think my Android App will access `/video_feed` route, and display video in a `ImageView`.

But I don't know if it is right or wrong. And how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would usually use a VideoView to show a video, setting it up with the URL to the video on your server.

For example:

```js
        //Create the video player and set the video path
        videoPlayerView = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.video_area);
        if (videoPlayerView == null) {
            Log.d("VideoPlayer Activity","onCreateView: videoPlayerView is null");
            return null;
        }

        //Set the video URI to the the URL of the video on the server
        videoPlayerView.setVideoURI(yourVideoURL);
```

Comment: But I don't know how to set up the URL video on server.. How can I do that?